# Number of items in a php loop depend on another loop

Tags: php, loops, dynamic-variables

I need to figure it out how to build a loop which number will depend on the number previously selected in another loop.

I'm building a small application to order some food. In my first loop in the HTML I added a snippet with php to select 1 to 5 element of a particular order:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="showHide" value="show">Spinach Dip Platter <span>$17.99 each</span>
<select name="spinach">
<option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Then, depends on how many items a customer is gonna select I want to give a limit to another loop, of a certain number. Let's say that he will select 2 items, in the next loop (which will be actually three loops of different breads) my customer can select only 2 items, instead of 5:

```
<label class="abread">
    <input type="checkbox" class="showHidetwo" value="show" name="alligatorbread">With Alligator or Turtle Bread add $3.00<br>
    <p>Turtle Bread</p>
    <select name="turtle">
        <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <p>Aligator Bread</p>
    <select name="alligator">
        <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <p>Spider Bread</p>
    <select name="spider">
        <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

Now the number is set to five, but I want to add a dynamic variable that will depend on the first loop (name="spinach") that will set the limit to the following loops. Is it possible?

UPDATE:

I tried something like that:

```
<label class="tray-items">
    <input type="checkbox" class="showHide" value="show">Spinach Dip Platter <span>$17.99 each</span>
    <p class="spinach">Sourdough</p>
    <select name="spinach_sour">
        <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        $spinach_sour = $_GET["spinach_sour"]; 
        ?>
    </select>
    <p class="spinach">Pumpernickle</p>
    <select name="spinach-pumper">
        <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
        for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        $spinach_pumper = $_GET["spinach_pumper"];
        ?>
    </select>
    <label class="abread">
        <input type="checkbox" class="showHidetwo" value="show" name="alligatorbread">With Alligator or Turtle Bread add $3.00<br>
        <p>Turtle Bread</p>
        <select name="turtle">
            <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
            for ($i=0; $i<=$spinach_pumper; $i++)
            {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <p>Aligator Bread</p>
        <select name="alligator">
            <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
            for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
            {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <p>Spider Bread</p>
        <select name="spider">
            <option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
            for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
            {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label>
</label>
```

Essentially I tried to get the first variable in a global get and after having assigned to the global varible I tried to export the value and reuse in the first of the second loop but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, replace `for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)` with `for ($i=0; $i<=$spinach; $i++)`?

Comment: Sure, but how can I save the value from the first loop to reuse it? $var = $_GET["spinach"]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matto, You can use variables in your for loop.

```
//make sure to declare your variable, but after that you can set the 
value to whatever you like

$var = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<$var; $i++) {
    //code goes here
}
```

Comment: what about the first step:
<select name="spinach">
<option selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option><?php
                    for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                   
                    ?>
This is an injection in the html, so how can I save, store and reuse the variable later? 
 $var = $_GET["spinach"];
Could be a good solution?

Comment: You'll need to submit the form, use javascript or start a session and store it in session variable. Also, your first option in your select is incorrect. If you don't have a value don't include value or if you want to set it to no value, set it to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Save the number you want into a variable name, which you said would be spinach and simply change your for loop to be:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $spinach; $i++)
```

Make sure that spinach is given a value otherwise you will run into problems.

Comment: I miss the first step, plus now I've got two loop in the first choise. How can I store the first varible?